# camel: response to a jetty http request is in encoded form, how to decode it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel

I am setting route as follows:

from producer template i am sending a body along with following headers

```
from("timer://test?period=2400000")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
.setHeader("Accept", simple("application/json"))
.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", simple("application/json"))
.setHeader("Content-Type", simple("application/json"))
.to("jetty:https://<url>?<proxysettings>").to(log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true)
```

produces following result, I have converted to hex format for better readability:

1f ef bf bd 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 ef bf bd 56 ef bf bd 4d 2d 2e 4e 4c 4f 55 ef bf bd 52 ef bf bd ef bf bd 4f ef bf bd ef bf bd 0b ef bf bd 2c 48 55 ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd 0b 73 ef bf bd ef bf bd 74 d1 b4 52 70 ef bf bd 4c ef bf bd 49 51 ef bf bd 2c 56 ef bf bd ef bf bd 2b 4b ef bf bd ef bf bd 4c ef bf bd 51 ef bf bd 51 2a 2e 49 2c 29 2d 76 ef bf bd 4f 01 ef bf bd 32 31 30 ef bf bd 05 00 6e 17 ef bf bd ef bf bd 45 00 00 00

Could someone here please help to decode this response?
response header shows some error but whats that error is not clear.

Response:
Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{Accept=application/json, Accept-Encoding=application/json, breadcrumbId=xxx, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpResponseCode=400, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=144, Content-Type=application/json, Date=Thu, 02 Nov 2017 09:20:52 GMT, firedTime=Thu Nov 02 14:50:51 IST 2017, Via=1.1 6b26b084edd2f59d401f06af6a91bb35.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), X-Amz-Cf-Id=xxx, x-amzn-RequestId=xxx, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=xxx, X-Cache=Error from cloudfront}, BodyType:byte[], Body:�....

Note:Successful request produces bigger response with a statusCode:200.
Note:endpoint is a aws instance.
if i post using postman i get proper response in string format.
I could not find any thread addressing this issue,